# jQuery single event for several DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, object

I'm trying to make a change event trigger for several objects in the DOM. Let me show you; I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select_something").change(function() {
        if (!($(".select_something option[value='0']").attr("selected"))) {
            $(".write_something").css('display','');
        }
        else
        {
            $(".write_something").css('display','none');
        }
    });
});
```

And with this I have several selectors/dropdowns all of which is called `.select_something`. When the option *is not* the default value (which is 0), it should show a `<textarea></textarea>` appear, again all of which is called `.write_something`.

All in all it's a quite simplistic function.

The problem I'm experiencing is that this only affects the very first `.select_something`, `.write_something` pair, and the rest is unaffected.

I've tried mixing around with `.find()`, `.parent()` and `.children()` to see if it could stick, but it don't.

How can I make it so all of my `.select_something`, `.write_something`pairs get changed when triggered?

*Edit: The IDs was supposed to be classes, of course.*

Comment: IDs have to be unique, having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid and the ID selector will only select the first element in the DOM with such an ID. Use classes instead.

Comment: Can you include your HTML .... `#` selectors in jQuery mean an `ID` attribute selector - IDs should be unique for DOM elements ... this is probably why its not working ...

Comment: From the code pasted we can see you know JQuery pretty well. Don't you know that `id` should be unique?

Comment: Very sorry, of course was the IDs supposed to be classes. A bit overworked, my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#select_something
```

Is an id.  IDs **must** be unique over your entire page.  If you have multiple elements with this same id, that's fundamentally wrong (and will cause you massive problems).

Having said that, the fix is easy: change those ids to css classes.

```
<select id="select_something">
```

becomes

```
<select class="select_something">
```

Then you could select against the css class, but of course you'll have to select the : `write_something` element relative to the current select.  Something like this might work depending on your structure:

```
$(".select_something").change(function() {
    if (!($("option[value='0']", this).attr("selected"))) {
        $(this).siblings(".write_something").css('display','');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).siblings(".write_something").css('display','none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Although in that case, the corresponding `.write_something` element has probably to be selected differently.

Comment: Thank you for your guidelines. Got my application working with a bit of tweaking to make the event act on the relative element. Very grateful for your help @AdamRackis!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a common class for the multiple objects, not a common ID.

The ID attribute is used to IDentify a single item. The CLASS attribute is used to define that an item is part of a group of items, all which have the same class name.

Use the class name `selectObject` on all of them, and then..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".selectObject").change(function() {

        //inside of an event, $(this) refers to the object that triggers the event,
        //in this case, the item that was clicked.

        if (!($(this).val()==0)) {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Here is something for illustration.
http://jsfiddle.net/FxLSR/1/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers and comments, only use an ID for unique elements, use a class for multiple elements.

This is how I would setup my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
   <select class="select_something"> ... </select>
   <textarea class="write_something"> ...</textarea>
</div>
<div>
   <select class="select_something"> ... </select>
   <textarea class="write_something"> ...</textarea>
</div>

etc...
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select_something").change(function() {
        if (!($(this).val() == "0") {
            $(this).next().show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).next().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

If the elements can't be placed next to each other as in the example HTML code I have given, then just make sure to select the textarea using some sort of relative selector such that you're not selecting all of the text areas. For example, if the two are siblings but they're not next to each other use: $(this).siblings(".write_something")

Comment: +1 but If that's your structure, why not use next() instead of parent().find() ?

Comment: good point, with that exact structure it would make more sense to use next().